# Using nested SQL in .vb file in asp.net

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

There are two tables in my database. One is 'Overview', the other is 'Exams'

'Overview' contains (id, tel, avgmark)
where id is the primary key;

'Exams' contains (id, examname, mark) 
where id and the examname form the primary key;

In my website, there is a page which allows users update a specific exam mark in 'Exams'.

My question is: how to update the (avgmark) in 'Overview' at the same time.

I have tried the below code, but error occurs.

Here is my SQL command and code:

```
    Private Sub UpdateOverview(id As Integer)
    Dim connect = New sqlConnection(connectionstring)
    Dim text as string ="UPDATE Overview SET avgmark = (SELECT AVG(mark) FROM   Exam GROUP BY id WHERE Overview.id = Exam.id AND Exam.id = @id)"
    Dim command = New sqlCommand(test)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id)
    connect.Open()
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connect.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: "but error occurs".... what error?

Comment: Your `Group By` and `Where` clauses are in the wrong order

Comment: Re Philipp: Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `HAVING` instead of `where`. Also you have to add where condition in your update query otherwise it will update all the records.

```
Private Sub UpdateOverview(id As Integer)
    Dim connect = New sqlConnection(connectionstring)
    Dim text as string ="UPDATE Overview SET avgmark = (SELECT AVG(mark) FROM   Exam GROUP BY id HAVING id = @id) WHERE id = @id"
    Dim command = New sqlCommand(test)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id)
    connect.Open()
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connect.Close()
    End Sub
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Overview t1
JOIN (
    SELECT AVG(mark) AS avg_mark, id
    FROM Exam
    WHERE id = @id
) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
SET t1.avgmark = t2.avg_mark
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim text as string ="UPDATE Overview SET avgmark = (SELECT AVG(mark) FROM Exam WHERE Overview.id = Exam.id AND Exam.id = @id GROUP BY id) WHERE Overview.id = idToUpdate"
```

Change the order of `group by` and `where`

the sql better formatted:

```
UPDATE Overview 
    SET avgmark = (SELECT AVG(mark) 
         FROM Exam 
         WHERE Overview.id = Exam.id AND Exam.id = @id 
         GROUP BY id) 
    WHERE Overview.id = idToUpdate
```